# Primefaces spinner - How to change width

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

If i change the Spinner width like below only the up/down arrow place is changed-the text area remains as default, how do i change the size of the spinner -including the text area.

```
<p:spinner id="spinnerBasic" style="width:50px;"/>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Primefaces spinner is a compound component consisting of a text field and the control elements. All this will be rendered inside a `<span>`.

If you only want to change the size of the text input, the `p:spinner` has a size attribute:

```
<p:spinner id="spinnerBasic" size="20"..../>
```

From the [primefaces documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html):

> size: Number of characters used to determine the width of the
>   input element.

The corresponding css class is `ui-spinner-input`. Changing the `width` attribute of this class to get the desired changes.