# Change size of spinner by css

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a webpage and i put a spinner like this below:

```
<p:spinner id="mySpinner" .. size="3">...</p:spinner>
```

How can i use css to change the size to make it responsive?

Comment: I found the answer to your question by googling, but make sure next time you post more context around your question, since the code is proprietary to the PrimeFaces java ui framework: http://www.primefaces.org/.

Comment: What is your current CSS. Can you provide a working example of your code with something like jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I found an answer for you here in another Stack Overflow post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080114/primefaces-spinner-how-to-change-width)

The "size" element is set to 20 by default, use this class to change it:

```css
.ui-spinner-input {
  width: 50px;
  /* Enter your own width above */
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to override spinner-border class width and height:

```css
.spinner-border {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please edit this so that the code is in a **code fence**.